# Function for calculating an optimal fit

Tags: python, function, optimization, integral

[image: Question with integral to be programmed into the function]

This is taken from a question paper for Python programming. 
I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from math import sin, pi

#Part a:
def f(x):
    return 2*x - x**2

def g(p,x):
    return p*sin(pi*x/2)


def hsum(p):
    s = 0
    for i,j in zip(np.arange(0,3,2E-4),np.arange(2E-4,3,2E-4)):
        delx = j - i
        ab = abs(f(i)-g(p,i))
        s += ab*delx
    return s



#print hsum(1)
#print hsum(0)        

#Part b:    
h = hsum(0)   
P = []
Q = []     
for p in np.arange(0,1.1,1E-3):
    k = hsum(p)
    if k<h:
        h = k
        P.append(hsum(p))
        Q.append(p)
print h
print min(P)
g = min(P)
t = P.index(g)
#print t
#print Q
print Q[t]
```

However, upon running it, the program returns a value of 0.001 for the so-called optimal P. This value should be close to 1 and before 1.1, according to the problem statement.

I thought that there may be a problem with floating points, but any combination I try gives me the same answer. 
Any suggestions?

EDIT: Using all the suggestions provided, I edited the original code and this one, although rather slow (runtime of 9:58!!), provides the correct answer of 1.071
Thanks for all the help. :D

Comment: NumPy isn't going to help you if you don't use any vectorized operations. All you're using it for is `arange`, and if you're just going to iterate over the range, that doesn't give any advantage over `xrange`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `hsum`, you reset `s` to `0` in every loop iteration. You should probably move that up, outside the loop.

In your code to find the best fit, you're appending the p values to P, but you don't keep any information about the quality of the fit. `min(P)` finds the lowest p, not the one that fits best. Store `(p, hsum(p))` tuples and find the minimum by the H(p) values. The min function takes a `key` argument that can help you with that. (With a bit of simplification, you wouldn't even need to make the tuples.)

Comment: Aah I understand the problem now. However, how exactly can I store the (p, hsum(p)) tuple and then ask the code to return the p corresponding to the smallest hsum(p)?